# Microsoft Speaker Recognition API: Why does the "verify" API call return "Resource or path can't be found."?

Tags: ruby, rest, voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

This is the verify function that I am calling:

```
def verify(verificationProfileId, pathToVoicePrint)

        soundFile = File.read(pathToVoicePrint)
        uri = URI("https://api.projectoxford.ai/spid/v1.0/verify?verificationProfileId=#{verificationProfileId}")
        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
        })

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
        # Request headers
        request['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
        # Request headers
        request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = @subscriptionKey
        # Request body
        request.body = soundFile

        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
            http.request(request)
        end
        return response
    end
```

I got this code directly from this page: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c

The JSON response from this API call is:

```
{ "error": { "code": "NotFound", "message": "Resource or path can't be found." } }
```

This error message is not listed anywhere on the docs. I'm also testing other functions, such as enrollment, where I'm using the same parameters (verificationProfileId and pathToVoicePrint) and those functions work, so I know they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruby snippet on dev.projectoxford.ai is erroneous, because a query is set in the URI ctor, but then wiped out in the subsequent line.  So you'll want either:

```
uri = URI("https://api.projectoxford.ai/spid/v1.0/verify?verificationProfileId=#{verificationProfileId}")
# don't overwrite the uri.query
```

or

```
uri = URI("https://api.projectoxford.ai/spid/v1.0/verify")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
    "verificationProfileId": "#{verificationProfileId}"
})
```